# How can i get width and height of Text?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get `width` and `height` of a `Text`?

```
Text(
   "吃葡萄不吐葡萄皮",
   style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 18
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 13):

You can get the size of text if you use a `TextPainter` or `Paragraph` object. Here is how you would do it with `TextPainter`:

```dart
final text = '不吃葡萄倒吐葡萄皮';
final style = TextStyle(fontSize: 30);

TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter()
  ..text = TextSpan(text: text, style: style)
  ..textDirection = TextDirection.ltr
  ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);

print(textPainter.size); // Size(270.0, 43.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually `Text` is widget and get height and width of any widget in flutter you have to use `GlobalKey` and assign it to our Widget.

```
GlobalKey txtKey = GlobalKey();
```

and set this key to `Text` widget

```
Text(
   key: txtKey,
   "吃葡萄不吐葡萄皮",
   style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 18
   ),
),
```

And you can access height/width by write below code else where may be in button press event!

```
    final keyContext = txtKey.currentContext;
    if (keyContext != null) {
          final txtBox = keyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          print('height ${txtBox.size.height} and width ${txtBox.size.width}');
    }
```

Here `txtBox` return exact size of your text.

Comment: Thank you!You really helped a lot.However, I want to know how to get the width and height of the font when I only have text and style？

Comment: I think you are looking for https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19264

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here is how you can get the `width` and `height` of a `Text` or any other  widget in Flutter.

```
GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
Size _size = Size.zero;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "吃葡萄不吐葡萄皮",
            key: _key,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Size"),
            onPressed: () => setState(() => _size = _key.currentContext.size),
          ),
          Text("Width = ${_size.width}, Height = ${_size.height}")
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap it into Container():

```
Container(
      width: 10.0,
      height: 20.0,
      child: Text(
        "吃葡萄不吐葡萄皮",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 18
        ),
      ),
    )
```